# MySQL password suddenly changed

Tags: mysql

Upon working on my computer, I noticed the computer's response started to become very slow. to speed it up, I opened the task manager and ended a few processes that seemed useless (one of which had the label 'MySQL'). Later on, I found out that the MySQL command line on my computer has stopped accepting my password (not sure how much .

I tried uninstalling MySQL (probably failed and uninstalled a different part of MySQL), and I even reinstalled the program, but it keeps asking me for the old password - and denying my access after every time I try typing it in.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could it be that you have had multiple instances of MySQL running at the same time, maybe because you tried installing it in separate locations?

Comment: I may be well wrong but I'm not sure uninstalling MySQL removes any of the actual data. I think the database data and the MySQL program are different entities, so you can reinstall MySQL but the database will remain the same. ?